# What is the ID of the Starred contacts group in the google contacts api

Tags: javascript, google-contacts-api

Is the starred group even a real group?

Can you access it with the group api?

This is the closest I have gotten:

http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/group/default?access_token=ya29.owFYVWvQ8nnKbxH4pdeB3gJ8-kME1cL0LcHCKQ3x7qhs7bbFfB2IdPVzOhqZNbtNkDQCu3f5by8ZRQ&group=http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/jonathan.carl.odonnell%40gmail.com/base/6

[image]

Comment: Your link returns a 403 for me.

Comment: That is because the token is not valid for your google user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group is a real, non-system group whose ID changes from account to account. When I accessed the group using the [google contacts API library I wrote](https://github.com/aliang/google_contacts_api/), the name of the group was "Starred in Android", so you can find it in your list of groups that way.

[Also see my response to the issue you opened on my repo.](https://github.com/aliang/google_contacts_api/issues/10)

Comment: Thanks Alvin. I am unable to find that group though. I am making this request on the web and not in android. I'm doing this through a rest request

Comment: The group was called "Starred in Android" even though I didn't star anything through an Android device. I think it's just the automatically generated name. Also, are you trying to get the group data, or the data for the contacts in that group?