# Starred contacts using Google API

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, gdata, google-contacts-api

Can I somehow know if the contact is starred using the Google API? I couldn't find a "Starred" or "IsStarred" property.

I know that [when you starred a contact using Android, then you can see a "Starred in Android" system group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31151310/what-is-the-id-of-the-starred-contacts-group-in-the-google-contacts-api), but that doesn't work when you do it [using the web version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knoBX.png).

Comment: There's no indication in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/) about it though, I'm guessing its more of a client feature than a service feature.